# C# - Windows Forms - Try to print - nothing is drawn - print dialog

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, dialog

Could you help me about C# 2010?

I want to print something by Print Dialog in Windows Forms.
But nothing is drawn in the paper in Open XPS Virtual Printer.
I have made a form with a button and a richTextBox.
I have used a sample code from a website and I changed that code a little.

here is the pictures:

[image]

here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FT_Pnt_01
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {



        PrintDialog PrintDialog1;


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // Declare the PrintDocument object.

        private System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument docToPrint =

            new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();




        // This method will set properties on the PrintDialog object and
        // then display the dialog.

        private void button_Print_01_Click(System.Object sender,

            System.EventArgs e)
        {


            // Allow the user to choose the page range he or she would
            // like to print.


            PrintDialog1.AllowSomePages = true;

            // Show the help button.

            PrintDialog1.ShowHelp = true;


            // Set the Document property to the PrintDocument for
            // which the PrintPage Event has been handled. To display the
            // dialog, either this property or the PrinterSettings property
            // must be set


            PrintDialog1.Document = docToPrint;

            DialogResult result = PrintDialog1.ShowDialog();


            // If the result is OK then print the document.

            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                docToPrint.Print();
            }


        }


        // The PrintDialog will print the document
        // by handling the document's PrintPage event.


        private void document_PrintPage(object sender,

            System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            // Insert code to render the page here.
            // This code will be called when the control is drawn.
            // The following code will render a simple
            // message on the printed document.


            string text = "پرینت گرفتن متن در سی شارپ";

            System.Drawing.Font printFont = new System.Drawing.Font

                ("Arial", 35, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular);



            MessageBox.Show("e.ToString() = " + e.ToString());




            // Draw the content.


            e.Graphics.Clear(Color.Blue);


            e.Graphics.DrawString(text, printFont,

                System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, 10, 10);


        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            PrintDialog1 = new PrintDialog();


        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears, from your provided example, you did not associate a method with the PrintPage event hander.  So your document_PrintPage() method never gets called.

I would add:

```
 docToPrint.PrintPage += document_PrintPage;
```

in the form’s constructor.

Example:

```
private PrintDocument docToPrint = new PrintDocument();

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    docToPrint.PrintPage += document_PrintPage;
}
```